# Formatting list of figures in Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word

When using References > Insert Table of Figures, I can manipulate it using Paragraph > Indentation > Hanging. However, I couldn't make it similar to the figure below.

Any suggestion how to format the list of figures in Word 2016 to look like the figure below? I'm using Word 2016.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestion how to format the list of figures in Word 2016 to look
>   like the figure below?

You can do this with style and tab definitions in the Table of Figures style and then some manual direct formatting. I am not aware of any other way to do this.

1. Adjust the Table of Figures style to include a Paragraph Indentation with a Hanging indent. (You already said you did that)
2. Add two tab settings to the style. One for where you want the figure description to start. This should be a Left set tab. The second tab to set is a Right tab and place it at the right margin. This one is important for the auto fill of the list to work properly.
3. Perform both #1 and #2 of this process using the Modify button on the Table of Figures dialog.
4. After creating the list you will have to manually insert a Tab between the Figure Number and the Description. You will also have to manually Bold each Figure label.
5. The example in the question shows the description text as justified left and right. This will have to be done manually by selecting the text and using the Justify (Ctrl + J) function of Word. You will also have to add manual line breaks if the description flows farther than you want.